# Setting raster pos not changing anything for DrawPixels in OpenGL

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl

I'm using SharpGL (OpenGL, WPF application) to draw a PNG on the screen. I opened the file, read in the bytes, and then used the following code to draw the image:

```
SharpGL.OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;

//gl.GetFloat(SharpGL.Enumerations.GetTarget.CurrentRasterPosition, data);
//gl.RasterPos(0, 0, 0, 1);
gl.DrawPixels(m_bitmapImage.PixelWidth, m_bitmapImage.PixelHeight, SharpGL.OpenGL.GL_BGRA, m_pixels);
```

I want to move the image around on the screen so it was my understanding that if I change the raster position that it would move starting point of where the image was drawn. If I change the values in raster position in any way, my image ends up disappearing. I tried to fetch the current raster position and pipe that directly into the `RasterPos` function and then try to read out the values again, it changes from `0, 0, 0, 1` to `258.5, 161.5, .5, 1` (half of my screen width, half of my screen height, don't know where .5 comes from, 1). Even if I manually try to fiddle with the numbers it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Where do you set your `GL_PROJECTION` and `GL_MODELVIEW` matrices?

Comment: I'm a total noob first off. I set the MatrixMode to GL_PROJECTION and then tried the code but no difference. Do I have to push two matricies on - one using PROJECTION and the other using MODELVIEW?

Comment: Without specifying matrices as @genpfault suggests, only geometry rendered inside of [-1,1] in x, y, and z (for z = 0, gets mapped to .5, as you've seen).  The trick with images is that they are clipped based on the visibility of the raster position (i.e., is the raster position inside of the viewing volume).  If the raster position is clipped, the entire image will be discarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho( 0, windowWidth, 0, windowHeight, -1, 1 );

glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();

glRasterPos( ... );
glDrawPixels( ... );
```

Or use [`glWindowPos()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glWindowPos.xml).

Comment: Didn't work. One note that I think may be important. My code is placed in a function that is called frequently based on a timer in the SharpGL library. Setting up the projection, is that a one-time thing is is that something that needs to happen on every iteration?

Comment: @mj_ addressing your "Setting up the projection" question, the answer is: it depends.  Think of the projection as the lens on the camera; if you never adjust the zoom, the lens setting is the same for all pictures you take.  The same for OpenGL; if you don't need to change the projection (which you might do if you want to zoom in on an object or out to see more of the scene), then you can set it once in your initialization routine, and not change it.  If you need to change it, then you need to update it before rendering.

Comment: As for what @genpfault mentioned, you could amend this by pushing and popping the projection stack, which would preserve your "normal" projection, and allow you to do your screen-aligned rendering, and then put things back to your original settings.  Or, if you just want to move the image around in the image plane, you can use the `glBitmap` command to do **relative** adjustments to the raster position.

Comment: @radical7, i haven't tried what you suggested yet, but i did try something else that I wanted to get your comment on. i put my drawpixels in there as it is and my image gets drawn (inverted) in the bottom, left hand corner of the window. on a whim, i put in a series of vertices in order to draw a polygon just to see where they would get drawn. the point of origin is the dead center of the screen. this was somewhat unexpected for me. Is there two coordinate systems that are in use in OpenGL? How can you switch between them? Why would my poly not start at bottom left?

Comment: @mj_ Assuming that both the model-view and projection matrices are the identity, and you've set the raster position to (0,0,0) (which is the default if you haven't called `glRasterPos` or friends), then what you describe is not what I would have expected.  Rather, the lower-left corner of the image should have been in the center.  My assumptions are probably wrong.  As for the inverted image, you can use `glPixelZoom` with a -1.0 as the Y scale; you'd also need to adjust the raster position in +Y by the size of the image (see `glBitmap` trick above).  Does that help?